# Extending the Magento OnePage checkout class

Tags: magento

I am adding an additional checkbox field to the Magento checkout for newsletter subscriptions via a new module.

So far I have added the code to my layout file (billing.phtml):

```
<p>Please untick this box if you do not wish to receive infrequent email updates and newsletters from us. <input type="checkbox" name="billing[is_subscribed]" title="" value="1" id="billing:is_subscribed" class="checkbox" checked="checked" /></p>
```

I have extended the class (`app/code/local/Clientname/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php`) - I have extended only the savebilling method:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Checkout
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * One page checkout processing model
 */

class Eatyourwords_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
{

    public function saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId)
    {
        if (empty($data)) {
            return array('error' => -1, 'message' => $this->_helper->__('Invalid data.'));
        }

        $address = $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();

        if (!empty($customerAddressId)) {
            $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
            if ($customerAddress->getId()) {
                if ($customerAddress->getCustomerId() != $this->getQuote()->getCustomerId()) {
                    return array('error' => 1,
                        'message' => $this->_helper->__('Customer Address is not valid.')
                    );
                }
                $address->importCustomerAddress($customerAddress);
            }
        } else {
            // process billing address and validate form
            /* @var $addressForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
            $addressForm    = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
            $addressForm->setFormCode('customer_address_edit')
                ->setEntity($address)
                ->setEntityType('customer_address')
                ->setIsAjaxRequest(Mage::app()->getRequest()->isAjax());
            // emulate request object
            $addressData    = $addressForm->extractData($addressForm->prepareRequest($data));
            $addressErrors  = $addressForm->validateData($addressData);
            if ($addressErrors !== true) {
                return array('error' => 1, 'message' => $addressErrors);
            }
            $addressForm->compactData($addressData);

            if (!empty($data['save_in_address_book'])) {
                $address->setSaveInAddressBook(1);
            }
        }

        // validate billing address
        if (($validateRes = $address->validate()) !== true) {
            return array('error' => 1, 'message' => $validateRes);
        }

        $address->implodeStreetAddress();

        if (true !== ($result = $this->_validateCustomerData($data))) {
            return $result;
        }

        if (!$this->getQuote()->getCustomerId() && self::METHOD_REGISTER == $this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()) {
            if ($this->_customerEmailExists($address->getEmail(), Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())) {
                return array('error' => 1, 'message' => $this->_customerEmailExistsMessage);
            }
        }

        if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
            /**
             * Billing address using otions
             */
            $usingCase = isset($data['use_for_shipping']) ? (int)$data['use_for_shipping'] : 0;

            switch($usingCase) {
                case 0:
                    $shipping = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
                    $shipping->setSameAsBilling(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $billing = clone $address;
                    $billing->unsAddressId()->unsAddressType();
                    $shipping = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
                    $shippingMethod = $shipping->getShippingMethod();
                    $shipping->addData($billing->getData())
                        ->setSameAsBilling(1)
                        ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
                        ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                    $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping', 'complete', true);
                    break;
            }
        }

        $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();

        if (isset($data['is_subscribed'])) {
            $status = Mage::getModel(‘newsletter/subscriber’)->subscribe($data['email']);
        }

        $this->getQuote()->save();

        $this->getCheckout()
            ->setStepData('billing', 'allow', true)
            ->setStepData('billing', 'complete', true)
            ->setStepData('shipping', 'allow', true);

        return array();
    }

}
```

Specifically towards the bottom of the class I have inserted:

```
if (isset($data['is_subscribed'])) {
            $status = Mage::getModel(‘newsletter/subscriber’)->subscribe($data['email']);
        }
```

I have added a file to let Magento know about the module (`app/etc/modules/Clientname_Checkout.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Clientname_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Clientname_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

However I am now stuck on the final step of how I get Magento to recognise and use the alernative save_billing method I have extended.  I think I need to add a file `/app/code/local/Clientname/config.xml`.

But I don't understand how I set this up so that the new savebilling class is used instead of the original.

Please can somebody help with this final step?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a textbook example of class overrides in Magento.  As you probably know, Magento uses a form of abstraction to load classes based on the contents of the XML configuration files dotted around the codebase.  This means we can load the model `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` by calling `Mage::getModel('checkout/type_onepage')`, with the default configuration.  A pretty cool feature is the ability to modify the mapping of the model reference, `checkout/type_onepage` to the actual class name.

#### Directory Structure

So you've done the hard work: editing the template and changing the model method.  Next you need to build a small module to perform the class rewriting.  Based on the name of your class, you're going to need a directory structure of the form:

```
/app
  /etc
    /modules
      /Eatyourwords_Checkout.xml
  /code
    /local
      /Eatyourwords
        /Checkout
          /etc
            /config.xml
          /Model
            /Type
              /Onepage.php
```

#### Performing the rewrite

The rewrite is handled in your module configuration file, `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <eyw_c>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </eyw_c>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eyw_c>Eatyourwords_Checkout_Model</eyw_c>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <type_onepage>Eatyourwords_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage</type_onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

The stuff in the `<modules />` tag group is just some standard bootstrapping for the module.

In the `<models />` section we are defining *namespace* to be used when loading any of our Model classes.  Much like the `checkout/type_onepage`, we can access any models we have in our `/Model` directory by appending `eyw_c/*`.

We then open up the `Mage_Checkout` model namespace, `<checkout />`, and perform a rewrite of the `checkout/type_onepage` class.  Now when Magento attempts to load `checkout/type_onepage` it will look for our class.  All other `checkout/*` classes will be unaffected.  The class name for them will be constructed in the normal manner.

#### Enable the module

Next we need to point Magento to the new module that we've created.  Your attempt was almost correct.  You should call it `Eatyourwords_Checkout.xml` and place it in `/app/etc/modules`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eatyourwords_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </Eatyourwords_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

..and that's it done.  Class overridden.

Comment: I think this is working and running the overridden class - though my code isn't working for the email subscription so maybe I have that wrong - need to debug!

Comment: @simonyoung: Sorry, I don't check that part!  You might need to call `->save()` on the model to flush it out to the database.